# create "pair key=value" file with SAS datastep

Tags: file, sas, keyvaluepair, datastep

I have to create a file from a dataset that is JSON style but without CR between each variable.
All variables have to be on the same line.

I would like to have something like that :

`ID1 "key1"="value1" "key2"="value2" .....`

Each key is a column of a dataset.
I work this SAS 9.3 on UNIX.

Sample :
I have

```
ID Name Sex Age
123 jerome M 30
345 william M 26
456 ingrid F 25`
```

I would like

```
123 "Name"="jerome" "sex"="M" "age"="30"
345 "Name"="william" "sex"="M" "age"="26"
456 "Name"="ingrid" "sex"="F" "age"="25"
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide some sample data, and show what you have tried so far, and state what specifically isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider these non-transposing variations:

Actual JSON, use `Proc JSON`

```
data have;input
ID Name $ Sex $ Age; datalines;
123 jerome M 30
345 william M 26
456 ingrid F 25
run;

filename out temp;
proc json out=out;
  export have;
run;

* What hath been wrought ?;
data _null_; infile out; input; put _infile_; run;

----- LOG -----

{"SASJSONExport":"1.0","SASTableData+HAVE":[{"ID":123,"Name":"jerome","Sex":"M","Age":30},{"ID":345,"Name":"william","Sex":"M","Age":26},{"ID":456,"Name":"ingrid","Sex":"F","Age":25}]}
```

A concise name-value pair output of the variables using the PUT statement specification syntax (*variable-list*) (*format-list*), using `_ALL_` for the variable list and `=` for the format.

```
filename out2 temp;
data _null_;
  set have;
  file out2;
  put (_all_) (=);
run;

data _null_;
  infile out2; input; put _infile_;
run;

----- LOG -----

ID=123 Name=jerome Sex=M Age=30
ID=345 Name=william Sex=M Age=26
ID=456 Name=ingrid Sex=F Age=25
```

Iterate the variables using the `VNEXT` routine. Extract the formatted values using `VVALUEX` function, and conditionally construct the quoted name and value parts.

```
filename out3 temp;
data _null_;
  set have;
  file out3;

  length _name_ $34 _value_ $32000;

  do _n_ = 1 by 1;
    call vnext(_name_);
    if _name_ = "_name_" then leave;
    if _n_ = 1 
      then _value_ =       strip(vvaluex(_name_));
      else _value_ = quote(strip(vvaluex(_name_)));
    _name_ = quote(trim(_name_));
    if _n_ = 1 
      then put _value_ @;
      else put _name_ +(-1) '=' _value_ @;
  end;
  put;
run;

data _null_;
  infile out3; input; put _infile_;
run;

----- LOG -----

123 "Name"="jerome" "Sex"="M" "Age"="30"
345 "Name"="william" "Sex"="M" "Age"="26"
456 "Name"="ingrid" "Sex"="F" "Age"="25"
```

Comment: This solution is perfect for me. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If your data looked like this...

```
Obs     Name      _NAME_        COL1

  1    Alfred     Name      Alfred
  2    Alfred     Sex       M
  3    Alfred     Age                 14
  4    Alfred     Height              69
  5    Alfred     Weight           112.5
  6    Alice      Name      Alice
  7    Alice      Sex       F
  8    Alice      Age                 13
  9    Alice      Height            56.5
 10    Alice      Weight              84
 11    Barbara    Name      Barbara
 12    Barbara    Sex       F
 13    Barbara    Age                 13
 14    Barbara    Height            65.3
 15    Barbara    Weight              98
 16    Carol      Name      Carol
 17    Carol      Sex       F
 18    Carol      Age                 14
 19    Carol      Height            62.8
 20    Carol      Weight           102.5
 21    Henry      Name      Henry
 22    Henry      Sex       M
 23    Henry      Age                 14
 24    Henry      Height            63.5
 25    Henry      Weight           102.5
```

You could use code like this to write the value pairs. Assuming this is what you're talking about.

```
189  data _null_;
190     do until(last.name);
191        set class;
192        by name;
193        col1 = left(col1);
194        if first.name then put name @;
195        put _name_:$quote.  +(-1) '=' col1:$quote. @;
196        end;
197     put;
198     run;

Alfred "Name"="Alfred" "Sex"="M" "Age"="14" "Height"="69" "Weight"="112.5"
Alice "Name"="Alice" "Sex"="F" "Age"="13" "Height"="56.5" "Weight"="84"
Barbara "Name"="Barbara" "Sex"="F" "Age"="13" "Height"="65.3" "Weight"="98"
Carol "Name"="Carol" "Sex"="F" "Age"="14" "Height"="62.8" "Weight"="102.5"
Henry "Name"="Henry" "Sex"="M" "Age"="14" "Height"="63.5" "Weight"="102.5"
NOTE: There were 25 observations read from the data set WORK.CLASS.
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I looked for. But how can I obtain the source date with _Name_ and Col1. PROC TRANSPOSE ?

Comment: proc transpose data=sashelp.class; by name; run; quit ; ?